# What happens to android app when a phone call interrupts the app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, phone-call

I am working on an app and in one of my activities I display a progressdialog. I have managed it so that it displays correctly during rotations, and I thought that would handle the case of a phone call too, but when I test it with a phone call the dialog goes away. So what exactly does the phone call do to the application and how is a part of the application lifecycle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

onPause and onStop are called, onDestroy may be called but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Long-press your home button and switch to another application... its basically the same thing.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html