# Android: How to detect a view is displayed on top of my activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an activity which is playing a video. When I get a phone call, system shows an overlay view top of my activity for phone ringing, but onPause() does not get called.

How can I detect my activity lost focus and pause the video?

**EDIT:**

I tested it on Nexus 4 onPause() gets called and then right after that onResume() gets called. But on Galaxy Tab 8 onPause() does not gets called.

Also for my Sony devices onPause() gets called since it shows a whole new activity when phone is ringing not an overlay view.

**EDIT 2:**

This is how it looks like when my Galaxy Tablet is ringing.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to android app when a phone call interrupts the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448380/what-happens-to-android-app-when-a-phone-call-interrupts-the-app)

Comment: Activty(and Fragments) `onPause()` *must* be called. Double-check your breakpoints positons.

Comment: @Adam No, actually it is not the same, since my phone does not create a new activity for showing phone ringing, and it just shows an overlay on top on my activity, and onPause() does not get called at all.

Comment: @kiruwka Actually I'm pausing the video inside onPause() but it's not getting called when phone is ringing, please look at the photo that I attached.

Comment: @Sirlate wow, very interesting. Can you make sure onStop, any other lifecycle callbacks also don't get called ?

Comment: @kiruwka No man, nothing is getting called.